# How to hide the console window of a C program?

Tags: c, window, hide

I've been looking around but I couldn't find the solution to my problem, even with some supposedly solved problems that resemble mine.

I want to hide the console window when my C program runs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500

int main(){   
    HWND hWnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_MINIMIZE );  //won't hide the window without SW_MINIMIZE
    ShowWindow( hWnd, SW_HIDE );
}
```

This is what I tried but the compiler gives me

> initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

and the fatal one which actually stops the compiling:

> undefined reference to 'GetConsoleWindow'

PS: I've checked *wincon.h* and the `GetConsoleWindow()` function is defined.

Comment: This could help you: [How to hide Console Window with WinAPI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096500/howto-hide-console-window-with-winapi)

Comment: Ken, I am using C not C++ and that thread solves a different problem, not this one. I already tried it out.

Comment: @Steve314, you're right. Going back and reading in more depth, it isn't. Removing my comment - can't undo the close vote, but don't want to direct others the wrong way. Thanks for the correction. :-) y Orionis, my apologies.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

(which is needed to use `GetConsoleWindow` - see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) must be *before*

```
#include <windows.h>
```

That `#define` is used by `windows.h` to know which version of Windows you are targeting (and thus which declarations it has to provide/which additional fields it has to add to structures/other magic that may be related to that linker error); if you define it *after* you include `windows.h` it will be useless.