# Problems with python file(.py) to executable(.exe) with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

TO BE MORE SPECIFIC: This program is not running AT ALL, only opening the command prompt and suddenly shutting down...
Heres my setup.py file...
I imported os and added the links to tcl and tk to prevent another issue for occurring. After solving that issue and now I am able to successfully build an .exe from my raw python code but, when opening the freshly created .exe file... All it will do it open a command prompt screen for mere milliseconds and close once again. I am assuming there was some build error possibly with tk.mainLoop() or tkinter in general? I am also importing the math module and a couple of other tkinter items such as tkinter.font and tkinter.messagebox. 
    Would really appreciate the help, I've been having a TON of issues with cx_Freeze and python-to-executable programs/modules in general...

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python36-32/tcl/tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'c:/python36-32/tcl/tk8.6'
base = None


executables = [Executable("formulas_tkinter_replace2.py", base=base, icon="pi-outline-128.ico")]
packages = ["tkinter", "math"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
    },
}

setup(
    name = "Formula",
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Mathematics made easy...',
    executables = executables
)
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Ok its Windows.

Comment: yes, sorry I went AFK.
Windows 10 to be specific.

Comment: OK thanks my answer might help then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the Tk and Tcl DLL are both missing.  There are two ways you correct this.

1)  This is more of a hack and only sometimes works but in this case it should:

Copy `tcl86t.dll` and `tk86t.dll` from your Python installation to the location of your exe.  These can be found at `Python36-32/DLLs`.  That's it.

2)  The 'proper' way to do it would be to do something like this:
Put this before executable:

```
files = {"include_files": ["C:/File_to_python/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "C:/File_to_python/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll"]}
```

and

```
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
        'build_exe':files 
    },
}
```

in the place of what you had before.

---

EDIT: Right.  This script should work.  I completely rewrote the setup script you provided however essentially what you did is correct however the error appeared because the file `tcl8.6` was not found and you also forgot to use the `include_files` function.  This can be done manually though.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "FilePathToPython/Python36-32/tcl/tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "FilePathToPython/Python36-32/tcl/tk8.6"
files = {"include_files":["FilePathToPython/Python36-32/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "FilePathToPython/Python36-32/DLLs/tk86t.dll", "pi-outline-128.ico"], "packages": ["tkinter"]}

base = None
setup( name = "Name of exe",
       version = "0.0",
       author = "Reader",
       description = "compile with setup.py build",
       options = {"build_exe": files},
       executables = [Executable("formulas_tkinter_replace2.py", icon="pi-outline-128.ico", base=base)])
```

Just replace what you need to.

As I already said.  You can hide the console completely by using `base = 'Win32GUI'`

Comment: Yes, i'm using windows. Sorry about going AFK. I will try this. I edited my main post to be clear that the program isn't running at all, I don't wish to just eliminate a quick command line flash from appearing on a working program. I just want any progress to actually perform, i'd be A-OK with the command line flashing by :(

Comment: Ah I'll have another look.  Is there an error message.  Run it from command prompt if it is too quick to see.

Comment: After adding 'Win32GUI', after re-building my python code with cx_freeze - I open up the new .exe file in the 'build' folder/directory and now I no longer  receive a random command prompt that appears\disappears in the blink of an eye. Now I am getting a windows error box that explains that I have a traceback error on line 14. I've never seen a error box listing the exact line of code in the same manner as an IDE would give you error info..

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  I'm very sorry.  I will work out the solution or delete this answer.

Comment: Don't worry about deleting anything; I'll just assume your efforts were fruitless. I appreciate the trouble.

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  Take a look and see if it helps now.

Comment: I shall try that, btw I just noticed this popped up in windows powershell while building..................................


    Missing modules:
? __main__ imported from bdb, pdb
? _dummy_threading imported from dummy_threading
? _frozen_importlib imported from importlib, importlib.abc
? _frozen_importlib_external imported from importlib, importlib._bootstrap, importlib.abc
? _posixsubprocess imported from subprocess
? _winreg imported from platform

Comment: ? grp imported from shutil, tarfile
? java.lang imported from platform
? org.python.core imported from copy, pickle
? os.path imported from os, pkgutil, py_compile, tracemalloc, unittest, unittest.util
? posix imported from os
? pwd imported from http.server, posixpath, shutil, tarfile, webbrowser
? termios imported from tty
? vms_lib imported from platform
This is not necessarily a problem - the modules may not be needed on this platform.

Comment: Yeah I got that as well.  My .exe works,  try what I suggested.  Any problems put them on here and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I am still getting a "can not find dll" error. Here are my imports, I think that dll files would have to do with that? I am only barely familiar with dll files, as far as I know they do routine actions so your computer doesn't do redundant processes over and over?
Imports: from tkinter import *, from tkinter import ttk,
from tkinter import font,
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring,
import math,
import tkinter.messagebox

Comment: I tried the proper method of directly linking the dll's path and by copying and pasting, I also tinkered around with the file paths a bit myself to no avail... Here is the file I am trying to make into an .exe btw. Maybe you can re-create the error I am encountering...

Comment: I added the code to the python file as another answer in this thread. I am not familiar with how to add the "code" formatting to a comment and I wanted to be neat and tidy for a few hundred lines of code... Sorry about the bulk but didn't want to make it unreadable/pointless by deleting things or removing empty lines.

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  See my edited answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Sorry, I went AFK again. maybe i'll talk to you in the morning if you're still game for this. I shall test it now after I get out playing with this Flask program really quickly.

Comment: @Michael Beyer Of course I am still game.  However I will not be available at all times tomorrow.  So you may need to wait a bit for a response.  But sure.  I am always around when you first asked this question and a while before.

Comment: You are a saint - It worked! You helped me learn how to do this in the future with other files as well! thank you!

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  Glad I could help. Cx_Freeze has a steep learning curve but once you know how to use it I doubt you will have another error again. You are probably going to hate me for saying this but keep trying with Cx_Freeze because this is about as difficult as it gets. Nice bit of Tkinter by the way I'm going to learn from that ; )

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  You may decide to [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for future visitors as it is a bit messy.

Answer (score 0):

Download pyinstaller-1.5.1 and Use python makespec.py --noconsole --onefile 'YourFile' and python build.py 'yourfile'/'yourfile.spec'

Comment: I am using 3.6 to be clear btw, thank you for the effort Skiller Dz

Comment: the pyinstaller have suport for python 3.6 go check

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of the python file I am attempting to make into an .exe... prepare for a few hundred lines of code... sorry.

```
 __author__ = 'Mike'; 'Intuitive Design'

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
import math
import tkinter.messagebox

# Variables & Core objects section
#   tk(), and ttk():
root = Tk()
root.config(bg='light grey')
root2 = ttk
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure('TButton', background="grey32", fg="white")
#   ______________
#   Frames:
frame = Frame(root)
frame2 = Frame(root, pady=10, width=400)
frame2.config(bg="grey10")
#   ______________
#   Program window:
root.title("Formula")
root.iconbitmap('pi-outline-128.ico')
#   ______________
#   Other:
box = tkinter.messagebox
output_txt = "Output here"
pi = math.pi
underscore = "_________________________________"
unnecessary = 1
code_to_get = 2
key_binding_to_work = 3
#   _______________
string_num = {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', 'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8',
              'nine': '9', 'ten': '10', 'eleven': '11', 'twelve': '12', 'thirteen': '13', 'fourteen': '14',
              'fifteen': '15', 'sixteen': '16', "seventeen": '17', 'eighteen': '18', 'eightteen': '18', 'nineteen': '19'
              , 'twenty': '20', 'twenty-one': '21', 'twenty-two': '22', 'twenty-three': '23', 'twenty-four': '24',
              'twenty-five': '25', 'twenty-six': '26', 'twenty-seven': '27', 'twenty-eight': '28', 'twenty-nine': '29',
              'thirty': '30', 'thirty-one': '31', 'thirty-two': '32', 'thirty-three': '33', 'thirty-four': '34',
              'thirty-five': '35', 'thirty-six': '36', 'thirty-seven': '37', 'thirty-eight': '38', 'thirty-nine': '39',
              'forty': '40', 'fourty': '40', 'forty-one': '41', 'forty-two': '42', 'forty-three': '43', 'forty-four':
              '44', 'forty-five': '45', 'forty-six': '46', 'forty-seven': '47', 'forty-eight': '48', 'forty-nine': '49',
              'fifty': '50', 'sixty': '60', 'seventy': '70', 'eighty': '80', 'ninety': '90', 'one-hundred': '100',
              'one-thousand': '1000', 'ten-thousand': '10000', 'one-hundred-thousand': '100000',
              'one-million': '1000000', 'one-billion': '1000000000', 'one-trillion': '1000000000000', 'vegeta':
              '9000', 'dragon-ball-z': '9000', 'goku': '9000'}
# ---(end of variable section)-----------------------

#   Functions: -----
args = [unnecessary, code_to_get, key_binding_to_work]
def radius_input(*args):
    try:
        output = entry_pi.get()
        radius = float(output)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            if ord(output[0]) >= 65 and ord(output[0]) <= 90:
                replacement = chr((ord(output[0]) + 32))
                output = output.replace(output[0], replacement)
            if " " in output:
                output = output.replace(" ", "-")
            output = output.replace(output, string_num[output])
            radius = float(output)

        except KeyError:
            try:
                if output[1] == '/':
                    first_num = int(output[0])
                    second_num = int(output[2])
                    answer = first_num / second_num
                    radius = float(answer)
                else:
                    box.showinfo("Error Occurred", "Sorry, you forgot the input or caused an unknown error!")
            except Exception:
                pass
    try:
        A = pi * (radius ** 2)
        A_spec = "{:,.5f}".format(A)
        # ------Background info (True value of circle's area; no rounding at all -----
        print("True Value: ", A, "\n", underscore)
        # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        print("Specific Value:", "\n", A_spec, "\n", underscore, "\n")
        entry_pi_out.delete(0, 100)
        entry_pi_out2.delete(0, 100)
        entry_pi_out.insert(0, A_spec)

        if A < A // 1 + 0.499995:
            A_rounddown = (A // 1)
            A_rounddown = "{:,}".format(A_rounddown)
            print("Rounded Value:", "\n", A_rounddown, "\n", underscore, "\n")
            entry_pi_out2.insert(0, A_rounddown)

        elif A >= A // 1 + 0.499995:
            A_roundup = (A // 1) + 1.0
            A_roundup = "{:,}".format(A_roundup)
            print("Rounded Value:", "\n", A_roundup, "\n", underscore, "\n")
            entry_pi_out2.insert(0, A_roundup)
        else:
            # You created an interesting error...
            box.showinfo("Ol' Easter Egg", """Easter egg no longer possible :( Who knows how you accessed it""")

        hist_A = str(A_spec)
        form_radius = "{:,}".format(radius)
        hist_r = str(form_radius)
        # π - storing the pi symbol in comment due to unicode string errors
        pie = u"π"
        hist_math = hist_r + "(r)" + "^2 * " + pie + " = " + hist_A + "\n"
        hist_prompt = hist_math
        history.insert(1.0, hist_prompt)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        pass


args = [unnecessary, code_to_get, key_binding_to_work]
def distance(*args):
    try:
        r = entry_rate.get()
        int_r = float(r)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            if ord(r[0]) >= 65 and ord(r[0]) <= 90:
                replacement = chr((ord(r[0]) + 32))
                r = r.replace(r[0], replacement)
            if " " in r:
                r = r.replace(" ", "-")
            r = r.replace(r, string_num[r])
            int_r = float(r)
        except KeyError:
            try:
                if r[1] == '/':
                    first_num = int(r[0])
                    second_num = int(r[2])
                    answer = first_num / second_num
                    int_r = float(answer)
                else:
                    box.showinfo("Error Occurred", "Sorry, you forgot the input or caused an unknown error!")
            except Exception:
                pass
    try:
        t = entry_time.get()
        int_t = float(t)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            if ord(t[0]) >= 65 and ord(t[0]) <= 90:
                replacement = chr((ord(t[0]) + 32))
                t = t.replace(t[0], replacement)
            if " " in t:
                t = t.replace(" ", "-")
            t = t.replace(t, string_num[t])
            int_t = float(t)
        except KeyError:
            try:
                if t[1] == '/':
                    first_num = int(t[0])
                    second_num = int(t[2])
                    answer = first_num / second_num
                    int_t = float(answer)
                else:
                    box.showinfo("Error Occurred", "Sorry, you forgot the input or caused an unknown error!")
            except Exception:
                pass
    try:
        D = int_r * int_t
        form_D = "{:,.2f}".format(D)
        print(form_D)
        entry_dist.delete(0, 100)
        entry_dist.insert(0, form_D)
        form_r = "{:,.2f}".format(int_r)
        form_t = "{:,.2f}".format(int_t)
        hist_prompt = form_r + "(r)" + " * " + form_t + "(t)" + " = " + form_D + "\n"
        history.insert(1.0, hist_prompt)
    except UnboundLocalError:
        pass


def leftclick(event):
    if entry_pi.get() == "Input Radius Here":
        entry_pi.delete(0, 100)
    else:
        pass

def leftclick2(event):
    if entry_pi_out.get() == "# Exact Value...":
        entry_pi_out.delete(0, 100)
    else:
        pass

def leftclick3(event):
    if entry_pi_out2.get() == "# Rounded Value ...":
        entry_pi_out2.delete(0, 100)
    else:
        pass

def leftclickdist(event):
    if entry_rate.get() == "Input Rate Here":
        entry_rate.delete(0, 100)
    else:
        pass

def leftclickdist2(event):
    if entry_time.get() == "Elapsed Time Value...":
        entry_time.delete(0, 100)
    else:
        pass

def leftclickdist3(event):
    if entry_dist.get() == "Distance Travelled":
        entry_dist.delete(0, 100)
    else:
        pass

def save():
    answer = ttk.tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Save:", "Are you sure you want to save your history?")
    if answer == "yes":
        file_name = askstring("File Name:", "What would you like to save it as? \n Please remember to specify\
    the file type (i.e. .txt, .csv, .doc, etc.)")
        fw = open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        write_var = history.get('1.0', END)
        fw.write(write_var)
        fw.close()
    else:
        pass

def clearAll():
    entry_dist.delete(0, 100)
    entry_time.delete(0, 100)
    entry_rate.delete(0, 100)
    entry_pi.delete(0, 100)
    entry_pi_out.delete(0, 100)
    entry_pi_out2.delete(0, 100)
    history.delete(1.0, 10000.0)
    entry_pi.insert(0, "Input Radius Here")
    entry_pi_out.insert(0, "# Exact Value...")
    entry_pi_out2.insert(0, "# Rounded Value ...")
    entry_rate.insert(0, "Input Rate Here")
    entry_time.insert(0, "Elapsed Time Value...")
    entry_dist.insert(0, "Distance Travelled")

y = ""
def current_formula(y):
    if y == "1":
        history.grid_remove()
        history.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="s", padx=6, pady=100)
        button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        entry_pi.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        entry_pi_out.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
        entry_pi_out2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=12)
        root.bind("<Return>", lambda x: radius_input(*args))
        button2.grid_remove()
        entry_rate.grid_remove()
        entry_time.grid_remove()
        entry_dist.grid_remove()
        one.config(bg="maroon")
    elif y == "2":
        history.grid_remove()
        history.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="s", padx=6, pady=100)
        button2.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
        entry_rate.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        entry_time.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
        entry_dist.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=12)
        root.bind("<Return>", lambda x: distance(*args))
        button1.grid_remove()
        entry_pi.grid_remove()
        entry_pi_out.grid_remove()
        entry_pi_out2.grid_remove()
        one.config(bg="paleturquoise4")
    else:
        one.config(bg="goldenrod4")
        try:
            history.grid_remove()
            entry_pi.delete(0, 100)
            entry_pi_out.delete(0, 100)
            entry_pi_out2.delete(0, 100)
            entry_rate.delete(0, 100)
            entry_time.delete(0, 100)
            entry_dist.delete(0, 100)
            entry_pi.insert(0, "Input Radius Here")
            entry_pi_out.insert(0, "# Exact Value...")
            entry_pi_out2.insert(0, "# Rounded Value ...")
            entry_rate.insert(0, "Input Rate Here")
            entry_time.insert(0, "Elapsed Time Value...")
            entry_dist.insert(0, "Distance Travelled")
            button1.grid_forget()
            entry_pi.grid_forget()
            entry_pi_out.grid_forget()
            entry_pi_out2.grid_forget()
            button2.grid_forget()
            entry_rate.grid_forget()
            entry_time.grid_forget()
            entry_dist.grid_forget()
        finally:
            pass
'''
button1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
entry_pi.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
entry_pi_out.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
entry_pi_out2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=12)
one.config(bg="maroon")
'''
# ----------------------

#   toolbar: -----
toolframe = Frame(root)
toolbar = Frame(toolframe, bg="gray7")
#   --------

#   Main: -----
#       Labels ---
one = Label(frame, pady=0, padx=20, width=31)
one_trim = Label(frame, bg="gray24", padx=1.5)
two = Label(toolbar, text="Formula", fg='gray34', font='broadway 24 bold italic', bg="gray10", pady=20, padx=20)

# complicated way to underline "Formula"... would only underline the 'o' without this... uses 'font' import @ top
f = font.Font(two, two.cget("font"))
f.configure(underline=True)
two.configure(font=f)
#       ----------

#       Button, entry boxes, answer boxes --
button1 = root2.Button(frame2, text="Area of a circle ", command=radius_input)
# very poorly written code... resulted in a random *args parameter, lambda statement, and the event to be bound to
# 'root' [i.e. Tk()] instead of button1. Please resolve this. *args is specified above 'radius_input()'.


entry_pi = ttk.Entry(frame2)
entry_pi.bind("<Button-1>", leftclick)

entry_pi_out = ttk.Entry(frame2)
entry_pi_out2 = ttk.Entry(frame2)
entry_pi_out.bind("<Button-1>", leftclick2)
entry_pi_out2.bind("<Button-1>", leftclick3)

button2 = root2.Button(frame2, text="Calculate Distance ", command=distance)
# same backwards *args parameter as 'button1' and 'radius_input()' suffer from are in 'button2' & 'distance()'

entry_rate = ttk.Entry(frame2)
entry_rate.bind("<Button-1>", leftclickdist)

entry_time = ttk.Entry(frame2)
entry_time.bind("<Button-1>", leftclickdist2)

entry_dist = ttk.Entry(frame2)
entry_dist.bind("<Button-1>", leftclickdist3)
#       -------------------------------------

# History text box -----
history = Text(one, height=20, width=30, spacing3=2.5)
# ----------------------------

#   --------

# Dropdown menu -------
menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
submenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=submenu)
submenu.add_command(label="Clear All", command=clearAll)
submenu.add_command(label="Save", command=save)
submenu.add_separator()
submenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: current_formula(""))
editmenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Formulas", menu=editmenu)
editmenu.add_command(label="Area of a circle", command=lambda: current_formula("1"))
editmenu.add_command(label="Distance Formula", command=lambda: current_formula("2"))
# ----------------------
# .pack ------
frame.pack(side="left", fill='y')
frame2.pack(side='right', fill='y')
one.pack(side='left', fill='y')
one_trim.pack(side='right', fill='y')
two.pack(side='top', pady=6)
toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
toolframe.pack(side="top", fill='x', padx=4)


# ----- end/loop program & execute remnant functions -----
current_formula(y)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I really appreciate how much time your taking to help me. It's nice since I've been delaying progress on this for a lot of time now and have moved on to java/android SDK stuff because of this.

Comment: I am just happy to help.  I might take a while but I will not give up!

Answer (score 0):

You asked about Win32GUI.  I am not entirely sure to be honest but I think it has something to do with the [Windows API.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)

The Cx_Freeze docs mention this:

Version 4.2.2 (December 2010)

> Use the Microsoft compiler on Windows for Python 2.6 and up as some strange behaviors were identified with Python 2.7 when compiled using mingw32.
>
> Eliminate warning about -mwindows when using the Microsoft compiler for building the Win32GUI base executable.

MinGW  is a C or C++ compiler.

It would make sense to use the Windows API since it can be used to [hide the console of a program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812095/hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-program).

If it does use the Windows API it seems Wikipedia has the answer to why its called "Win32GUI":

> User Interface
> [9] Provides the functions to create and manage screen windows and most basic controls, such as buttons and scrollbars, receive mouse and keyboard input, and other functions associated with the graphical user interface (GUI) part of Windows. This functional unit resides in user.exe on 16-bit Windows, and user32.dll on 32-bit Windows. Since Windows XP versions, the basic controls reside in comctl32.dll, together with the common controls (Common Control Library).

So basically it looks like the GUI is still in 32 bit version even for 64 bit computers.  Therefore they would refer to it as Win32GUI because it is in 32 bit version.  The Cx_Freeze developers would not risk calling it "Win64GUI" in case a 64 bit version **was** created.

Comment: True, I suppose it takes some time to get the masses to adopt new software. Years ago I would have assumed the not only would we have universally adopted 64-bit systems but, that we would be on our way to 128-bit OS's being available more freely (I'm pretty sure they are out there for servers especially?)

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  'Years ago I would have assumed the not only would we have universally adopted 64-bit systems but, that we would be on our way to 128-bit OS's being available more freely' I agree 100%, ' I suppose it takes some time to get the masses to adopt new software'  I have to disagree with that.  They could update it all to 64 bit without the masses ever even knowing.  Microsoft seems to have come to halt.  Only yesterday I was told that Microsoft's compiler Visual Studio did not even support the latest version of C (that was released years ago) until recently.

Comment: @MichaelBeyer You can distribute both 64 bit and 32 bit software and it will look exactly the same.

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  Yes I think you are right about the servers as well.

Comment: My basic understanding is that, the more bits an OS can handle means a computer can send more data (i.e 32 bits/4 bytes vs. 64 bits/8 bytes) in a single data packet. Wouldn't this lead to GPU's and CPU's being able to process more data and then in turn allow hardware to compute with more performance?

Comment: I have never noticed a difference between 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems, I've just always known that they process more data.

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  Performance will be much better.  You mention you do not notice the difference.  If you are talking about speed no you will not unless what you are processing is very large eg 3d graphics.

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  I was so interested by your `Win32GUI` question I decided to ask it as it's own separate question. [You can see it here if your interested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703965/why-does-cx-freeze-use-win32gui-rather-than-win64gui#comment82368619_477039651).  I did this because I am not entirely sure myself and I thought it deserved it's own question (it seems it did not though).

Comment: I was positive I replied to you but, It seems like I did not. I wish you got some more answers on that question though!

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  I hoped that too.  That's why I have not yet accepted it we may still get answers.  I don't like the answer "just because it's always been that way".  Anyway I'll ping you whenever a new one comes in so you don't have to keep looking.

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  No problem.  It's the least I can do :)

Comment: @MichaelBeyer  It seems to confirm what I said previously.  Take a look at the comments below the answer.