# Why does cx_Freeze use Win32GUI rather than Win64GUI?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

The command line of an application built with cx_Freeze can be hidden with `Win32GUI`.

Why does cx_Freeze choose to reference `Win32GUI` rather than `Win64GUI`?

This suggests that cx_Freeze has either not been updated to include this feature, or is calling a 32 bit command and yet almost all Windows computers are now 64 bit.

Is there a reason why the inplamenters chose to call it this?

I have researched for a long time but have not found any answer, any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: ask cx_Freeze's author. it is not place for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply because that is how it started. Even now it is called the "Win32" subsystem, even though it is 64-bit!

Comment: Thanks but from your answer the "`Win32`" part do you mean Windows OS or cx_Freeze?

Comment: Windows uses that term itself.

Comment: Like the [Win32 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Yep, that's it. :-)