# How to perform a ping-test programmatically on Windows?

Tags: c, cmd, request, ip, ping

I'd like to make an IP-test in a C command line program on **Windows** .

Now I'm using the cmd-command in my program with something like this:

```
if(system("ping -c1 8.8.8.8  -w 2 ") == 0){
    printf("request successful\n");
    return true; 
}else{
    printf("request not successful\n");
    return false;
}
```

Please note that the code above is just an example: with my program I will try to ping some devices, to see if they are online; if not I know there is a connection issue. Since I need only the connection status there is no need to show up the results.

Is there another way to do the same **programmatically**, so without cmd-window? Just like a hidden request in the background.

Comment: You want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812095/hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-program)

Comment: Also how do you want to communicate the message?

Comment: @Simon I think that the OP is asking how to perform a ping programmatically.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni  I don't follow.  If they hide the terminal, how will they know the result? They either want to pass it to something else, and hide the terminal, or it will just run and close

Comment: @Simon I suppose that they need to understand if a remote peer (in this case Google's DNS) is reachable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Are you using Windows? Is your program a command line (console) program or a GUI program? Do I understand right that you get a new console window for the `ping` program and you want to hide this?

Comment: Hey :) This part of my code is just an example, with the program I will try to ping some devices, to see if the devices are online. If there are not online I know there is a connection issue. So @RobertoCaboni yes I try to make a ping programmatically, for this reason, there is no need to show up the results, because the if-statement interpret, if the request was successful or not. I'm using Windows and it's a command line console, the information of the ping show up in the command line console of the program, so there is no another console showing up.

Comment: I still want the console but without the informations of the ping request, just something like this: 
IP: 192.168.xxx.xxx: successfull
IP: 192.168.xxx.xxx: not successfull
Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I've provided an answer that will probably satisfy your needs. If you agree, then, the question can be edited in order to make it more clear: 1) you are using windows, 2) you need a programmatical check of reachability with ping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If on *Windows* you need to check programmatically if an host is reachable, I suggest using **`_popen()`** instead of `system()`.

In fact with ***pipes*** you can execute a command like with `system()`, but in addition its output is redirected to a stream. After that you can access the stream exactly how you'd do with a file, reading the output and parsing whatever you need.

At [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=vs-2019) you can find Microsoft official documentation for `_popen()`. You will be easily able to find all related functions (such as `_pclose()`).

In the following demonstrative program a `ping` command is sent (asking for only two echoes to Google DNS server in order to save time). Then the obtained `FILE *`, opened in textual read mode, is used to access the stream with a *normal* loop of `fread()` calls:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };

int main( void )
{
    FILE * pipe = _popen( "ping 8.8.8.8 -n 2", "rt" );
    if( pipe != NULL )
    {
        int rd = 0, ret;
    
        while( ( ret = fread( buffer+rd, 1, BUFFER_SIZE - rd, pipe ) ) > 0 )
        {
            rd += ret;
        }
    
        if( strstr( buffer, "TTL=" ) != NULL )
        {
            printf( "\nThe host is reachable!\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "\nThe host is NOT reachable!\n" );
        }
    
        //printf( "%d bytes read\n\n%s\n", rd, buffer );

        _pclose( pipe );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Error in pipe opening!\n" );  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Some further explanation

- In this example only simple host *reachability* is verified. An host is considered reachable if at least an echo comes back. It is a starting point for any other information you might need to parse.
- I've done it by checking the presence of `TTL=` substring, that I'm sure will be present in every language in case of successful ping (the output may be printed in different languages according to PC settings).
- Tailor your buffer size to the length you expect is required to find the needed substring. In my example 1024 bytes were far enough for the expected response length.
- You can find, commented, the print of the whole buffer. You can use that string to check **everything** you need (for example average ping time).
- In order to read from the stream, feel free to use your favourite function. Another popular alternative would be `fgets()`, that would be great to read and parse one line at a time, and would also require a smaller reading buffer.

---

### Similar in Linux

Though the question is about Windows, I have to say that the implementation on Linux would be very similar, based on `popen()`, `pclose()` and so on.

You can find the description of the mentioned functions in the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: Thank You! This is exactly what I'm searching for!