# Executing ls in a different directory in C using exec

Tags: c, exec, ls

Title is pretty self-explanatory on what I want to do.

My current try:

```
  chdir("/Path/I/want/");   //this is different that the path my program is located at
      char * ls_args[] = { "ls" , "ls -l", NULL};
      execv(ls_args[0], ls_args);
    }
```

I am not getting any errors or output, any help?

Comment: Why changing dir and not simply issuing `ls /Path/you/want/`?

Comment: Two reasons: 
1-I need to create a text file in this directory and I don't know how to do it directly (I realize this isn't the topic of the question but since you asked I am answering).

2-I tried `char * ls_args[] = { "ls /Path/I/want" , "-l", NULL)` then 
      `execv(ls_args[0], ls_args)`

and it also resulted in no output so this was my attempt at trying to fix it.

Comment: 1) Also the file can be created at a given path (for example specifying the full path in `fopen()` . 2) In order to access the ouptut of the executed command use `popen()` (on Linux) or `_popen()` (on Windows). I explain the use of the latter in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61010544/11336762 (even if for a different command).

Comment: I am well aware of this and thank you for mentioning but I was asked to do it using `exec` , not my choice but I really appreciate you mentioning this.

Comment: In this case it's a bit more complicated, since `exec` functions do not provide a stream of the executed program's output that can be read from the calling program. This question explains how to do: you have to do a pipe (that's what popen() actually does..): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292642/grabbing-output-from-exec

Comment: Alternatively you can just redirect the output to a file (something like `ls path > . out.txt`) and process it trough `fopen()`, `fgets()` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execv function needs full path of the command which you have to execute. So, instead of giving `"ls"`, you should find out where the ls is located in your system by

`$ which ls`

it will probably be in /bin folder.
So you have to give `"/bin/ls"` to exec.
Also any argument to ls should be another member in array.
So instead of using

`char * ls_args[] = { "ls" , "ls -l", NULL};`

use

`char * ls_args[] = { "/bin/ls" , "-l", NULL};`